# Given an input of fragment positions in a shader, how can I blur each fragment position with an airy disc?

Tags: opengl, game-development, directx-11, fragment-shader

I am attempting to create a reasonably interactive N-body simulation, with the novelty of being able to observe the simulation from the surface of one of the bodies. By this, I mean that I have some randomly placed 'stars' of very high masses with random velocities and 'planets' of smaller masses given initial circular velocities around these stars. I am then rendering this in real-time via OpenGL on Linux and DirectX11 on Windows.

My question is in regards to rendering the scene out, NOT the N-body simulation. I have a very efficient/accurate solver working now, and it can always be improved later without affecting the rendering.

The problem obviously arises that stars are obscenely far away from each other, thus the fragment shader is incapable of rendering distant stars as they are fractions of pixels in size. Using a logarithmic depth-buffer works fine for standing on a planet and looking at a moon and the host star, but I am really struggling on how to deal with the distant stars. I am not interested in 'faking' it, or rendering a star map centered on the player, as the whole point is to be able to view the simulation in real time. A.k.a the star your planet is orbiting is ~1e6m away and is rendered as a sphere, as it has a radius ~1e4 m. Other stars are ~1e8m away from you, so they show up as single lit pixels (sometimes) with a far Z-plane of ~1e13.

I think I have an idea/plan, but I think it involves knowledge/techniques I am not aware of yet.

Rationale:

1. Have world space of stars on a given frame
2. This gives us 'screen' space, or fragment position, of star's center of mass in fragment shader
3. Rather than render this as a scaled sphere, we can try to mimic what our eye's actually do: convolve this point (pixel) with an airy disc (or gaussian or whatever is most efficient, doesn't matter) so that stars are rendered instead as 'blurs' on the sky, with their 'bigness' depending on their luminosity and distance (in essence re-creating the magnitude system for free)
4. Theoretically this would enable me to change the 'lens' parameters of my airy disc at will in order to produce things that look reasonably accurate/artistic.

The problem: I have no idea how to achieve this blurring effect!

I have some basic understanding of shaders, and have different render passes going on currently, but this seems to involve things I have not stumbled upon, or even how to achieve this effect.

TLDR: given an input of a fragment position, how can I blur it in a fragment/pixel shader with an airy disc/gaussian/etc.?

I thought a logarithmic depth buffer would work initially, but obviously that only helps with z-fighting, not dealing with angular size of far away objects.

Comment: "the fragment shader is incapable of rendering distant stars as they are fractions of pixels in size" - usually this is rounded up to 1 pixel, I think. If not, you can draw them as points.

Comment: You may be over-thinking the airy disc. For stars smaller than a pixel, just render a square with an airy disc texture. Draw your distant stars differently than your close stars. This is not "faking", this is just how computer graphics works.

Comment: That is a good idea, simply rendering a texture at the given position. However, I would lose the ability to change the diameter of the lens to change the disc size dynamically. Not that important though, just disappointing. I have temperatures of stars too, so I can color the texture this way as well.

Comment: When the lens diameter changes, use a different texture. You can compute a new texture whenever it changes, or just have several different ones.

Comment: That is so simple! Thank you, I was totally over-thinking this problem.

Comment: I suppose that for the nearby star, the effect of the disc becomes a small additional blurry halo around the star? then you render the blurry halo, or you just don't bother if it is too small to notice. Again, not faking, just normal real-time rendering. (I *assume* you want the rendering to run in real time and you will make reasonable tradeoffs to make that work, but if not, then you can do the real convolution)

Comment: I was thinking of using a distance threshold, so for stars that are so far away from my floating origin I can throw them in this 'airy-disc' pass. For my host star I can render it normally. We don't perceive the airy disc for our sun so I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-thinking it. For stars smaller than a pixel, just render a square with an Airy disc texture. This is not "faking" - this is just how [real-time] computer graphics works.

If the lens diameter changes, calculate a new Airy disc texture.

For stars that are a few pixels big (do they exist?) maybe you want to render a few-pixel sphere convolved with an Airy disc, then use that texture. Asking the GPU to do convolution every frame is a waste of time, unless you really need it to. If the size really is only a few pixels, you could alternatively render a few copies of the single-pixel texture, overlapping itself and 1 pixel apart. Though computing the texture would allow you to have precision smaller than a pixel, if that's something you need.

For the nearby stars, the Airy disc from each pixel sums up to make a halo, I think? Then you just render a halo, instead of doing the convolution. It isn't cheating, I swear.

If you really do want to do a convolution, you can do it directly: render everything to a texture by using a framebuffer, and then render that texture onto the screen, using a shader that reads from several adjacent texture pixels, and multiplies them by the kernel. Since this runs for every pixel multiplied by the size of the kernel, it quickly gets expensive, the more pixels you want to sample for the convolution, so you may prefer to skip some and make it approximate. If you are not doing real-time rendering then you can make it as slow as you want, of course.

When game developers do a Gaussian blur (quite common) or a box blur, they do a separate X blur and Y blur. This works because the convolution of an X blur and a Y blur is a 2D blur, but I don't know if this works for the Airy disc function. It minimizes the number of pixels sampled for the convolutions.

Comment: I think this answer is the best of both worlds: it offers a means of solving the problem more efficiently (just use a precomputed texture for a given lens), while also directly answering the question (render to a framebuffer, then 2D blur).